# How do i set the requestPayloadType parameter to a HashMap using Java DSL

Tags: spring-integration, dsl

I have the below Integration flow using java DSL and i want to add **requestPayloadType** as java.util.HashMap. 
How do i do that?
I want the JSON input to be auto recognised as JSON and not as byte

```
public IntegrationFlow NotificationFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Http.inboundChannelAdapter("/passenger")
                    .requestChannel(inputChannel())
                    .autoStartup(true)
                    .id("httpInnboundPass")
                    .requestMapping(r -> r.consumes("application/json"))
                    .**requestPayloadType**()
                    )
            .enrichHeaders(hes -> hes.header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
            .channel("inputChannel")
            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't clear. There is really that method there:

```
Http.inboundChannelAdapter("/passenger")
                .requestPayloadType(HashMap.class)
```